# F# function negation chain

Tags: f#

I want to negate the return value of a function in a cool way.

Given this function:

```
let yes = fun() -> true
```

I want to implement no as a negation of yes

```
let no = not yes //doesn't work
```

Does any kind of syntatic sugar exist in F# to make this possible?

P.S.
I am not looking for this:

```
let no = fun() -> not yes() // boring
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work:

```
let no = not << yes
```

Comment: Right, this is basic function composition, just use the function composition operator.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353882.aspx